# Boost::spirit::qi parser not consuming entire string

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I'm creating a grammar for a simple calculator, but I'm having trouble hammering out the reason why one specific test case is not working.  Here is a functional example of my parser:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_char.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_parse.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_bind.hpp>
using namespace boost::spirit;
using namespace boost::phoenix;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

void fPushOp(const string& op){
  cout << "PushOp: " << op << endl;
}

void fPushInt(string& my_str){
  cout << "PushInt: " << my_str << endl;
}

template<class Iterator>
struct Calculator : public qi::grammar<Iterator> {

    qi::rule<Iterator>  
      expression, logical_or_expression, logical_and_expression, negate_expression, series_expression,
      single_expression, inclusive_or_expression, exclusive_or_expression, and_expression, equality_expression, 
      relational_expression, shift_expression, additive_expression, multiplicative_expression, 
      term, complement_factor, factor, number, integer, variable, variable_combo, word, result;

    Calculator() : Calculator::base_type(result)
    {
          number = 
              lexeme[
                qi::as_string[
                    ("0x" >> +qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F"))     
                  | ("0b" >> +qi::char_("0-1"))
                  | ("0" >>  +qi::char_("0-7"))
                  | +qi::char_("0-9")
                ] [bind(&fPushInt, qi::_1)]
              ] 
             ;

          complement_factor = number
              | ('~' >> number)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_COMPLEMENT")]
              | ('!' >> number)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_NEGATE")];
              ;
          term = complement_factor
            >> *( (".." >> complement_factor)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_LEGER")]
                | ('\\' >> complement_factor)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_MASK")]
                ); 
          multiplicative_expression = term
            >> *( ('/' >> term)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_DIV")]
                | ('%' >> term)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_MOD")]
                | ('*' >> term)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_MUL")]
                );
          additive_expression = multiplicative_expression
            >> *( ('+' >> multiplicative_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_ADD")]
                | ('-' >> multiplicative_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_SUB")]
                );
          shift_expression = additive_expression
            >> *( (">>" >> additive_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_SRL")]
                | ("<<" >> additive_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_SLL")]
                );
          relational_expression = shift_expression
            >> *( ('<' >> shift_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_LT")]
                | ('>' >> shift_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_GT")]
                | ("<=" >> shift_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_LET")]
                | (">=" >> shift_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_GET")]
                );
          equality_expression = relational_expression 
            >> *( ("==" >> relational_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_EQ")]
                | ("!=" >> relational_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_NEQ")] 
                );
          and_expression = equality_expression 
            >> *(('&' >> equality_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_AND")]); 
          exclusive_or_expression = and_expression 
            >> *(('^' >> and_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_XOR")]); 
          inclusive_or_expression = exclusive_or_expression 
            >> *(('|' >> exclusive_or_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_OR")]); 
          single_expression = inclusive_or_expression;
          series_expression = inclusive_or_expression 
            >> *((',' >> inclusive_or_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_SERIES")]);
          logical_and_expression = series_expression
            >> *(("&&" >> series_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_LOGICAL_AND")]); 
          logical_or_expression = logical_and_expression 
            >> *(("||" >> logical_and_expression)[bind(&fPushOp, "OP_LOGICAL_OR")]);
          expression = logical_or_expression;

          result = expression;
    }
};

int main(){
  Calculator<string::const_iterator> calc;
  const string expr("!3 && 0,1");
  string::const_iterator it = expr.begin();
  parse(it, expr.end(), calc, qi::space);
  cout << "Remaining: " << (string(it,expr.end())) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The expected output is the following:

```
PushInt: 3
PushOp: OP_NEGATE
PushInt: 0
PushInt: 1
PushOp: OP_SERIES
PushOp: OP_LOGICAL_AND
Remaining:
```

The current output when `expr` is `!3 && 0,1` seems to indicate that `&& 0,1` does not get consumed:

```
PushInt: 3
PushOp: OP_NEGATE
Remaining:  && 0,1
```

If `expr` is `!3&&0,1`, then it works just fine.  With a `qi::space` skipper being used when invoking `qi::parse`, I don't see how these two strings are seen differently.  Can anyone point me towards the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rules don't declare the skipper:

```
qi::rule<Iterator>
```

and hence, they are *implicitly `lexeme`s*. For a background on `lexeme[]` in relation to skippers, see [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)

To correctly apply a skipper

- you need to declare the skipper at the grammar and rule definitions

  ```
  template<class Iterator, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
  struct Calculator : public qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper> {

      qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper>  
        expression, logical_or_expression, logical_and_expression, negate_expression, series_expression,
        single_expression, inclusive_or_expression, exclusive_or_expression, and_expression, equality_expression, 
        relational_expression, shift_expression, additive_expression, multiplicative_expression, 
        term, complement_factor, factor, result;

      qi::rule<Iterator>  
        number, integer, variable, variable_combo, word;
  ```
- need to use `phrase_parse` while passing an instance of the skipper type

  ```
  phrase_parse(it, expr.end(), calc, qi::space);
  ```

#### Fixed Code

Further notes:

- cleaned up the includes (prefer to include the full `phoenix.hpp` because you *will* get bitten by inexplicable bugs if you are missing subtle bits. Of course, if you know which bits, feel free to reduce compile times by selectively including sub-headers)
- I *vehemently* advice against `using namespace` unless absolutely necessary. In this case, you easily sollicit confusion between one of the many brands of `bind`. And, no, just saying `using boost::phoenix::ref` is not enough, because

  ```
  using boost::phoenix::ref;
  std::string s;
  bind(foo, ref(s))();
  ```

  ends up using `std::ref`, not `boost::phoenix::ref` due to ADL

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

void fPushOp(const std::string& op){
    std::cout << "PushOp: " << op << std::endl;
}

void fPushInt(std::string& my_str){
    std::cout << "PushInt: " << my_str << std::endl;
}

template<class Iterator, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct Calculator : public qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper> {

    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper>  
      expression, logical_or_expression, logical_and_expression,
        negate_expression, series_expression, single_expression,
        inclusive_or_expression, exclusive_or_expression, and_expression,
        equality_expression, relational_expression, shift_expression,
        additive_expression, multiplicative_expression, term,
        complement_factor, factor, result;

    qi::rule<Iterator>  
        number, integer, variable, variable_combo, word;

    Calculator() : Calculator::base_type(result)
    {
        number = 
            qi::lexeme[
              qi::as_string[
                  ("0x" >> +qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F"))     
                | ("0b" >> +qi::char_("0-1"))
                | ("0" >>  +qi::char_("0-7"))
                | +qi::char_("0-9")
              ] [phx::bind(&fPushInt, qi::_1)]
            ] 
           ;

        complement_factor = number
            | ('~' >> number)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_COMPLEMENT")]
            | ('!' >> number)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_NEGATE")];
            ;
        term = complement_factor
          >> *( (".." >> complement_factor)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_LEGER")]
              | ('\\' >> complement_factor)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_MASK")]
              ); 
        multiplicative_expression = term
          >> *( ('/' >> term)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_DIV")]
              | ('%' >> term)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_MOD")]
              | ('*' >> term)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_MUL")]
              );
        additive_expression = multiplicative_expression
          >> *( ('+' >> multiplicative_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_ADD")]
              | ('-' >> multiplicative_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_SUB")]
              );
        shift_expression = additive_expression
          >> *( (">>" >> additive_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_SRL")]
              | ("<<" >> additive_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_SLL")]
              );
        relational_expression = shift_expression
          >> *( ('<' >> shift_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_LT")]
              | ('>' >> shift_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_GT")]
              | ("<=" >> shift_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_LET")]
              | (">=" >> shift_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_GET")]
              );
        equality_expression = relational_expression 
          >> *( ("==" >> relational_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_EQ")]
              | ("!=" >> relational_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_NEQ")] 
              );
        and_expression = equality_expression 
          >> *(('&' >> equality_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_AND")]); 
        exclusive_or_expression = and_expression 
          >> *(('^' >> and_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_XOR")]); 
        inclusive_or_expression = exclusive_or_expression 
          >> *(('|' >> exclusive_or_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_OR")]); 
        single_expression = inclusive_or_expression;
        series_expression = inclusive_or_expression 
          >> *((',' >> inclusive_or_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_SERIES")]);
        logical_and_expression = series_expression
          >> *(("&&" >> series_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_LOGICAL_AND")]); 
        logical_or_expression = logical_and_expression 
          >> *(("||" >> logical_and_expression)[phx::bind(&fPushOp, "OP_LOGICAL_OR")]);
        expression = logical_or_expression;

        result = expression;
    }
};

int main(){
  Calculator<std::string::const_iterator> calc;

  const std::string expr("!3 && 0,1");
  std::string::const_iterator it = expr.begin();

  phrase_parse(it, expr.end(), calc, qi::space);

  std::cout << "Remaining: " << std::string(it,expr.end()) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought the `qi::space` in `parse(it, expr.end(), calc, qi::space);` does the same thing?

Comment: It just tells the parser API what Skipper _instance_ to pass, but the grammar ignores it!

Comment: I've explained the steps needed to fix, and posted [a working sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7553a4c5955fd28c)

Comment: I can't seem to get your working sample to compile? `boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp:303: error: no match for call to '(const boost::function<bool(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, ...`

Comment: I can only assume you didn't copy/paste it all :) Consider copying again since I improved a few more things. See also the remarks in the answer.

Comment: ahh it was `phrase_parse` vs `parse`.  I'll have to go explore what the difference between it all was.  Thank you very much!